# The letter disapperaed after Splitting string in my ruby program

Tags: ruby

I am newbie in ruby. In my ruby program, there is a part of code for parsing geocode. The code is like below:

```
  string = "GPS:3;S23.164865;E113.428970;88"
  info = string.tr("GPS:",'')
  info_array = info.split(";")
  puts "GPS: #{info_array[0]},#{info_array[1]},#{info_array[2]}"
```

The code should split the string into 3 piece: `3`, `S23.164865` and `E113.428970;88` and the expected output is

```
GPS: 3,S23.164865,E113.428970
```

but the result is:

```
GPS: 3,23.164865,E113.428970
```

Yes, the `'S'` letter disappered...

If I use

```
  string = "GPS:3;N23.164865;E113.428970;88"
  info = string.tr("GPS:",'')
  info_array = info.split(";")
  puts "GPS: #{info_array[0]},#{info_array[1]},#{info_array[2]}"
```

, it prints expected result

```
GPS: 3,N23.164865,E113.428970
```

I am very confused why this happens. Can you help?

Comment: You have shown the "expected output", but not the *rule* that produces that results for your example. There are many rules that would generate that result. Moreover, presumably you want the rule to apply for other strings as well. An example of such a rule would be "return a string formed by joining elements of an array with a comma, where the array contains three strings, the first being `"GPS: "` followed by the digit(s) following `"GPS:"`, the second being the string between the first and second semi-colon and the third being the string between the second and third semicolon".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were expecting [`String#tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-tr) to behave like [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-gsub).

Calling `string.tr("GPS:", '')` does not replace the complete string `"GPS:"` with the empty string. Instead, it replaces *any character* from within the string `"GPS:"` with an empty string. Commonly you will find `.tr()` called with an equal number of input and replacement characters, and in that case the input character is replaced by the output character in the corresponding position. But the way you have called it with only the empty string `''` as its translation argument, will delete any of `G, P, S, :` from anywhere within the string.

```
>> "String with S and G and a: P".tr("GPS:", '')
=> "tring with  and  and a "
```

Instead, use `.gsub('GPS:', '')` to replace the complete match as a group.

```
string = "GPS:3;S23.164865;E113.428970;88"
info = string.gsub('GPS:', '')
info_array = info.split(";")
puts "GPS: #{info_array[0]},#{info_array[1]},#{info_array[2]}"

# prints
GPS: 3,S23.164865,E113.428970
```

Here we've called `.gsub()` with a string argument. It is probably more often called with a regexp search match argument though.